# Accidental Remote Desktop Lockout. IPSec Authentication Required

Tags: powershell, authentication, remote-desktop, ipsec, windows-firewall

I didnt find any questions like this when i searched.

I messed up pretty badly, we had someone hack our system recently and in an attempt to prevent this in the future I was exploring windows firewall "Remote Desktop (TCP-In)" inbound connection settings. I clicked Allow connection only if secured, but meant to click cancel on the properties window knowing that it requires the connection to be "authenticated and integrity protected" with IPSec. In a most stupendous show of idiocy I accidentally pressed the button next to it, Apply.

What will allow me to connect to remote desktop to the windows 7 server "securely" as windows firewall defines it so that i can fix this horrible mess?

I have read through this

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd759062(v=ws.11)

The security was still set at default, so only the first option, with header "Allow the connection if it is authenticated and integrity-protected" applies.

but I dont know how to configure remote desktop to be secured with IPSec, can anyone help me accomplish this?

or if there is another way, like using powershell to connect to the server remotely and editing the firewall rule from there, that would be welcome as well.

Thank you very much for any assistance you can offer.

Edit: I have the Administrator Username and Password available to me and the Server is at nearly vanilla settings for a Windows 7 server.

Comment: Windows 7 is not a server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Windows?  Is it in a domain?  If in a domain, you could create a group policy that was targeted to apply to that computer only, then set it to disable the Windows firewall.

If Powershell remoting is enabled and you can access it, you could temporarily disable the windows firewall using this command.

```
 Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False
```

Since this is Windows 7, and the mostly default config, one other option might be to use [PSExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). Using PSExec, you may be to get a remote command prompt, and stop the firewall.

Comment: the server is not in a domain. Its generally at vanilla settings for a windows 7 server. modified the question to include this

Comment: I have attempted to use Powershell and received this error

Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic

Comment: I will try PSExec immediately

Comment: If you can get remote or local access to an elevated command prompt on the computer you can reset the Windows Firewall back to it's default configuration with the following command: **netsh advfirewall reset**.

Comment: This is what i've got so far.
C:\>psinfo \\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -u "USERNAME" -p "PASSWORD"

Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...Cannot connect to remote registry on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:
The network path was not found.
Could not connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:
The network path was not found.

C:\>sc \\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX config RemoteRegisty start=auto

[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 1722:
The RPC server is unavailable.

Comment: So it looks like remote procedure call is still disabled by default. is there a way around that?

Comment: No, you are probably screwed. At this point you are going to probably need to get physical access or something.

Comment: I was afraid of that, that's fine. we can. 
On a possibly tangential point from my original question, how does one go about allowing only a specific user to remote in without going through IPSec as setting specific users through Firewall seems to require that.

Comment: Only users that are in the 'Administrators' or 'Remote Desktop Users' groups on the machine will have remote access via RDP.  Even better might be to setup some kind of VPN (openvpn/tinc/etc) where the VPN deals with the authentication.

Comment: If you can send me a reference for where to find a guide on setting up a vpn to tunnel with IPSec, It would be much appreciated, I have a VPN, but can't figure out how to get the encryption to be IPSec.

or if you know how to disable the non administrator 'Remote Desktop Users' from using remote desktop, that would be wonderful too. 

we have exactly one and only one account that needs to be able to remote into this computer.